# Component does not get updated after calling `this.forceUpdate();`

Tags: react-native

I am using [direct manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html) to change the color of a view, every time a specific event occurs.

My render function:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View
          ref={component => this._view = component}
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
      </View> 
    );
```

My update function that is called every time a specific event occurs:

```
  onSlideChangeHandle(index) {
    this._view.backgroundColor = 'red'
    this._view.forceUpdate()
  }
```

Do I need to do something more to force the component to change the color? The method is called, and the property is updated. Unfortunately, the UI is not updated calling the force update. Do I miss something? I know I should use the state to update the components, but for this specific case I really need direct manipulation.

Comment: can you explain why you can't use the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I need to update the background color using the `setNativeProps`.

```
onSlideChangeHandle(index) {
    this._view.setNativeProps({ style: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    } });
}
```